# How would you do a moderation analysis?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interaction, psychology, mancova

I'm currently analysing data on an experiment I have run in connection to my BA thesis, but as I'm not that statistically strong, I have run into difficulties and I hope you will be able to help.

With this experiment, I test if exposure to green products affect subsequent moral and prosocial behaviour.

The experiment is as follows:
Participants are allocated to one of three conditions (Organic, Fairtrade and Control)
Then their moral behaviour, their personal value endorsement (Biospheric and Altruistic values), and their prosocial behaviour is measured.

Analysis:

1) I test, if treatments affect moral and prosocial behaviour (ANOVAs)
The problem:

2) I would like to test, If value endorsement moderates the effect of exposure. That is, I want to test if the interactions between conditions and the two value endorsements are significant.
How would I go about testing this?

- My supervisor advised me to use MANCOVA (Moral + Prosocial as independent; Treatment as categorical dependent; and the two values as covariates). Would you do the same? I have never used MANCOVA before and have no textbooks on this, and under the current COVID-19 circumstances it is not possible for me to get my hands on any. I am able to do the analysis, but I'm just wondering, if there's a more correct way to test it (Taking into account that this is "just" a BA thesis).

I hope, that you will be able to shed some light on this. Thanks.